# Avoiding virtual function calls in numerical C++

Tags: c++, templates, optimization

I'm writing some numerical simulation code in C++. In this simulation, there are some things that are "local", having a floating point value at every point on a two-dimensional grid, and others that are "global", having only a single global floating point value.

Aside from this difference, the two types of object behave similarly, and so I would like to be able to have an array that contains both types of object. However, because this is a numerical simulation, I need to do this in a way that (a) avoids virtual function call overheads as much as possible, and (b) allows the compiler to use optimisations as much as possible - and in particular, allows the compiler to do SIMD auto-vecotorisation where possible.

Currently I'm finding myself writing code like this (which, I now realise, will not actually work as intended):

```
class Base {};

class Local: public Base {
public:
    float data[size];
    // plus constructors etc.
};

class Global: public Base {
public:
    float data;
    // ...
};

void doStuff(Local a, Local b) {
    for (int i; i<size; ++i) {
        a.data[i] += b.data[i];
    }
}

void doStuff(Local a, Global b) {
    for (int i; i<size; ++i) {
        a.data[i] += b.data;
    }
}

void doStuff(Global a, Local b) {
    for (int i; i<size; ++i) {
        a.data += b.data[i];
    }
}

void doStuff(Global a, Global b) {
    a.data += b.data*size;
}
```

My code is a bit more complex than this - the array is two dimensional, and there are several `doStuff`-type functions that have three rather than two arguments, so I have to write eight specialisations for each one.

The reason this doesn't work as intended is that the types of the arguments to `doStuff` are not actually known at compile time. What I want to do is to have an array of `Base *` and to call `doStuff` on two of its members. I then want the correct specialisation of `doStuff` to be called for the specific types of its arguments. (It doesn't matter if there's a virtual method call involved in `doStuff` - I just want to avoid them in the inner loop.)

The point of doing it this way rather than (for example) overloading `operator[]` is that the compiler can (hopefully) do SIMD auto-vectorisation for `doStuff(Local, Local)` and `doStuff(Local, Global)`, and I can lose the loop entirely in `doStuff(Global, Global)`. Perhaps there are other compiler optimisations that can happen in these functions as well.

However, it's annoying to have to write such repetitive code. Consequently I'm wondering whether there's a way to achieve this using templates, so that I can just write one function `doStuff(Base, Base)` and code equivalent to the above will be generated. (I hope that gcc is smart enough to optimise away the loop in the case of `doStuff(Global, Global)`.)

I stress that the following solution is *not* what I'm looking for, since it involves a virtual function call on every iteration through the loop, which adds overhead and probably prevents a lot of compiler optimisations.

```
class Base {
    virtual float &operator[](int) = 0;
};

class Local: public Base {
    float data[size];
public:
    float &operator[](int i) {
        return data[i];
    }
    // …
};

class Global: public Base {
    float data;
public:
    float &operator[](int i) {
        return data;
    }
    // ...
};

void doStuff(Base a, Base b) {
    for (int i; i<size; ++i) {
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve a similar effect to the above, but without the overhead of a virtual function call on every iteration through the inner loop. (Unless I'm completely wrong, and the compiler can actually optimise away all the virtual function calls and generate code like the above. In that case you could save me a lot of time by telling me this!)

I did have a look at [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but it's not obvious how to adapt it to this case, at least not to me, because of the multiple overloaded arguments to `doStuff`.

Comment: Sound like a job for templates to me.

Comment: @EJP me too! That's why I said so in the question. But it isn't at all obvious to me how to use templates to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have the answer. A template function like this should work (though I don't know where `size` is coming from):

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void doStuff(A & a, B & b) {
    for (int i; i<size; ++i) {
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
}
```

Here you have an overloaded `operator[]` but it isn't virtual.

---

If you don't know at call time what types you have, but you have a fixed number of derived types, then creating a static dispatch is an option

```
void doStuff( Base & a, Base & b ) {
    Local * a_local = dynamic_cast<Local*>(&a);
    Global * a_global = dynamic_cast<Global*>(&a);
    //same for b
    if( a_local && b_local ) {
        doStuffImpl(*a, *b); {
    } else if( a_local && b_global ) {
        doStuffImpl(*a, *b):
    } ...
}
```

You'll notice the code in the if block is the same for every condition, assuming `doStuffImpl` is a template function. I'd suggest wrapping this up in a macro to reduce the code overhead. You may also wish to track the type on your own and no use `dynamic_cast`. Have an enum in your `Base` class which explicitly lists the types. This is a safety mechanism that basically prevents unknown derived classes from appearing at `doStuff`.

Unfortunately this type of approach is required. It's the only way to convert from dynamic types to static ones. And if you wish to use templates you need the static ones.

Comment: This will work fine if the types of A and B are known at compile time, but they aren't in my case. I realise the question isn't very clear about that - I will edit it.

Comment: (`size` is just a const defined in some header somewhere.)

Comment: Are the number of derived types constant or unlimited? That is, can you know all the possible types statically in `doStuff`?

Comment: Constant - as far as I can imagine, there will only ever be two derived types, Global and Local.

Comment: Thanks for the updated version. It seems as if there should be some clever way to avoid the repetition using templates in this case. I can't quite see how, but I've posted it as another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139344/c-static-dispatch-using-templates

Comment: I've tried to implement it this way, but unfortunately the templated `doStuff` function won't compile, because there's no `operator[]` in `Base`. Is this a fixable problem?

Comment: The template function should have no mention of the `Base` class. It will look like the first code bit I gave in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake somewhere in my implementation - implementing it using this toy example rather than my actual code does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK in your code for `Local` to know about `Global` and `Global` to know about `Local`?

If the answer to the above question is yes, you can the avoid cost of a virtual function for every point in the domain by one virtual function call and couple of dynamic casts.

```
class Base {
    public:
       virtual void doStuff(Base& b) = 0;
};

class Local: public Base {
    public:
       virtual void doStuff(Base& b);
       float data[size];
       // plus constructors etc.
};

class Global: public Base {
    public:
       virtual void doStuff(Base& b);
       float data;
       // ...
};

void Local::doStuff(Base& b) {
    Local* lb = NULL;
    Global* gb = NULL;
    if ( NULL != (lb = dynamic_cast<Local*>(&b)) )
    {
       // Do Local+Local stuff.
    }
    else if ( NULL != (gb = dynamic_cast<Global*>(&b)))
    {
       // Do Local+Global stuff.
    }

}

void Global::doStuff(Base& b) {
    Local* lb = NULL;
    Global* gb = NULL;
    if ( NULL != (lb = dynamic_cast<Local*>(&b)) )
    {
       // Do Global+Local stuff.
    }
    else if ( NULL != (gb = dynamic_cast<Global*>(&b)))
    {
       // Do Global+Global stuff.
    }

}

void doStuff(Base a, Base b) {
    a.doStuff(b);
}
```