# C++ static dispatch using templates

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have some C++ code that looks like this:

```
class Base {
    virtual void dummy() = 0;
    // this is to generate a vtable, but note there is no virtual f()
};

class A : public Base {
public:
    void f() { /* ... */ };
    void dummy() {};
}

class B : public Base {
public:
    void f() { /* different implementation from A */ };
    void dummy() {};
}

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
void doStuff(T1 &x, T2 &y, T3 &z) {
    for (i=1; i<100000; ++i) {
        x.f();
        y.f();
        z.f();
    }
}
```

The intention here is to avoid virtual function calls to `f()` during that inner loop, in order to allow compiler optimisations. (This is obviously a simplified version of my actual code. For details of my use case, see this [more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138009/avoiding-virtual-function-calls-in-numerical-c/22138841?noredirect=1#22138841)).

This works fine if the types of `doStuff`'s arguments are known at run-time, but if they're not then it fails:

```
int main() {
    Base *x = new A();
    Base *y = new B();
    Base *z = new A();

    doStuff(*x, *y, *z); 
    // oops - this instantiates to doStuff(Base &, Base &, Base &)
    // and there's no Base::f().
}
```

to get around this (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138009/avoiding-virtual-function-calls-in-numerical-c/22138332#22138332)) it seems I have to construct a static dispatch function explicitly:

```
void doStuff(Base &x, Base &y, Base &z) {
    A *a_x = dynamic_cast<A*>(&x);
    B *b_x = dynamic_cast<B*>(&x);
    A *a_y = dynamic_cast<A*>(&y);
    B *b_y = dynamic_cast<B*>(&y);
    A *a_z = dynamic_cast<A*>(&z);
    B *b_z = dynamic_cast<B*>(&z);
    if (a_x && a_y && a_z) {
        doStuff(*a_x, &a_y, &a_z);
    } else if (a_x && a_y && b_z) {
        doStuff(*a_x, &a_y, &b_z);
    } 
    // ... and so on for all eight combinations of A and B.
}
```

But that's some pretty annoyingly repetitive code, and if I have several functions along the lines of `doStuff` it will quickly get unmanageable, especially if any of them have four or more arguments.

So my question is, is there any way to avoid this repetitive code? It seems like some further clever use of templates should be able to eliminate it, but I can't quite see how to do it.

Comment: Templates might be hard, but Boost's preprocessor library can likely help you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/

Comment: dynamic_cast will work only for the hierarchy classes with vtable

Comment: @Alex it seems to be ok if I add a virtual dummy method to the base class - I've edited the post.

Comment: Actually the code as a whole doesn't work - the template `doStuff` function won't compile, because there's no `Base::f()`. So it seems I need to find a different solution to this problem anyway.

Comment: Actually it does work, if you fix a few typos. [Live demo](http://ideone.com/YzxE5q).

Comment: @n.m. thanks! It seems to work with my compiler as well, so I must have made a mistake in my other implementation (which was using my actual code, not this simple example.).

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question: "static dispatch" - unfortunately your problem requires finding out the type at runtime... You want to identify the actual type from some base class pointers. This will work only at runtime.

Using `dynamic_cast` is a hack, the usage of dynamic_cast along usually means bad OO design. BTW, my bet would be that using `dynamic_cast` (`dynamic_cast` can be pretty slow!) and then a static function call is slower than simply making `f()` virtual and putting it to your base class and calling it that way.

Of course your case is a bit more special, you want to perform something else for all 8 cases but this is a piece of dirt work you won't be able to solve elegantly with brief code in C++ in my opinion. It is possible to forge a solution that is less error prone/easy to extend or one that is better in performance but none of them will be brief and/or elegant. Your current `doStuff()` implementation is rather a less error prone "bulletproof" solution, another one ugly solution has just came to my mind that would have good performance even for a lot of derived classes and class combinations (own type enum with own gettype + switch) but that is ugly as hell.

Summing it up: This problem has no nice solution in C++. You have to rethink your design or you have to live with ugly code when it comes to problems that can not be solved elegantly in C++: for example in case of serialization you often find ugly code like this...

Comment: It is bad OO design! Unfortunately bad design is a natural consequence of SIMD parallelism being a compiler optimisation rather than a language feature - that's the reason for needing to construct it this way. Note that `f()` is called 100000 times in succession (which can be vectorised by the compiler), whereas the `dynamic cast` would only called once, so it's a comparatively very small cost. But yes, I tend to think you're probably right that there's no elegant way to do this. (But it can't hurt to ask.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical multiple-dispatch problem. It's very well developed in the literature. One of the solutions is the Visitor pattern (you need to apply it twice as you have 3 arguments to dispatch on). Another one is a `map<tuple<type_info, type_info, type_info>, StuffDoer>` (the latter class should have a virtual `doStuff` method and do a dynamic_cast to all arguments inside).

Comment: If you have time, could you point me towards a sketch of what that second solution would look like? I haven't used STL since the 90s, so it's hard for me to imagine the code.